# Slowing down the Selenium process in easyb

Tags: grails, selenium, groovy, easyb

I m trying to slow down the BDD process in easyb and automated selenium , using

```
    `selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000000")`
```

line but it doesnt seems to be working is there any thing else i need to add between each line to slow down each steps performed by the automated selenium in easyb test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000000")`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#waitForPageToLoad%28java.lang.String%29)  sets how long Selenium will wait for a page to load before timing out.

If the page loads before the 3000000ms is up, then it moves on immediately.

To actually slow down Selenium as it clicks on elements etc, you can set:
[`selenium.setSpeed("milliseconds")`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#setSpeed%28java.lang.String%29)